# How to fix psexec not running PowerShell script on VM?

Tags: powershell, scripting, virtual-machine, psexec

I am using PsExec to run a PowerShell Script on a VM. I execute psexec like this

`psexec \\ip -c -i -u Admin -p password PowerShell C:\Path to PowerShellscript on computer`

PowerShell runs and it opens on the VM but immediately closes. It gives me this message in cmd on my computer

```
PowerShell.exe exited on ip with error code 1
```

How do I proceed to fix this so I can run the PowerShell script that is on my computer onto the VM?

Comment: Can you pipe the output of the script to a text file and see what the error code is `> log.txt 2>&1`

Comment: I have a log for the script but it doesn't mention any error code

Comment: If you append `> a.txt 2>&1` to your command you can catch the error.

Comment: So I have my transcript set up like this: _Start-Transcript -Path $Log  -Force_ and then at the end of my script I have this _}Stop-Transcript_. Where would I append _> a .txt 2>&1_ ?

Comment: Also my log doesn't work if I run the script using psexec. Any ideas why?

Comment: I'd recommend you to run only powershell.exe (without path to the script) and then inside of console manually run your script and check if this is working.

Comment: Ok, now I see what it is. I have something wrong in my script. My script is for removing certain users and the term 'Remove-LocalUser' is not recognized. Is there any other way to write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `-c` when I executed *psexec* and that seemed to make it work.